# Delays in java.rmi.Naming.bind()

Tags: java, rmi

A driver from one of our vendors suddenly started failing last week, on a machine where it has worked for almost a year.  The last two descriptive messages output by the driver are now three minutes apart (whereas before they were seconds).  Reverse-engineering the code, I've found that the three minute delays happen during calls to java.rmi.Naming.bind().

What's my starting point for troubleshooting this and getting more information out of the call to bind()?  It does not return a success or failure indication, and it does not appear to be throwing any Exceptions.  I would assume that the consistent 3-minute delay means that some timeout is being hit at some point during the process, but then why is there no indication of failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

java RMI appears to log to java.util.logging.  So, configure java.util.logging to see what Java RMI is doing, so you can debug the problem.

(In my case, we use log4j, so I found a library to route java.util.logging messages to log4j.)

With logging enabled, we discovered that RMI was spending three minutes trying to connect to a wrong IP address that it thought was localhost, thanks to a wrong entry somebody had added to our hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a DNS problem. Check the DNS lookup and reverse lookup times. Naming.bind() itself is trivial, at both ends.

Comment: A network trace would verify this and rule out any other LDAP (I assume) issues. WireShark and tcpdump are your friends here - you can filter out DNS and LDAP traffic and look at timestamps.

Comment: @AngerClown LDAP has nothing to do with it. This is an RMI Registry API.

Comment: DNS and reverse DNS lookups appear to be pretty fast, although reverse lookup results are pretty spotty for hosts on our network -- but I think that is because the admins around here don't offer reverse DNS lookup.  Is there any way to get logging or debug data out of the call to Naming.bind() ?  This operation is not the same as a DNS bind, is it?

Comment: @skiphoppy No it isn't the same as a DNS bind. Your netadmins need educating. Java does reverse DNS lookups by the zillion. There is really no excuse for not having them working properly.

Comment: On another machine where this driver works, a reverse DNS lookup for the machine's own IP address fails.  Can you give me a sample reverse DNS lookup that should work on a working machine but fail on a failing machine?  I'm sorry for being so clueless, but I need something I can take back to the admins on this machine.